# Weird. Query works in Fuseki HTML form but not from JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, invoke, aspnetdb

I would like to ask some questions regarding the use of threads. I have looked at a lot of posts and links suggested from those posts but still came up blank.
I have a NetBeans project that has a few classes. One of them is the Gui class that I use to just click a button and some processing gets performed. From the Gui I call an instance of another class that in turn calls other classes. One of these classes submits a Sparql query to a TDB backend database. All output is saved to files for now.

What I would like to do is to somehow make the class called from the Gui to run on another thread and also to be able to update an EditorPane and a TextArea on the Gui from one or more of the called classes. Up to now I have tried calling an instance of the Gui class and use a public method within but this does not work. I am calling the instance Gui with

```
Gui gui = new Gui();
gui.setEditorPaneText("File name is: " + fn);
```

and the method in the Gui class is

```
public void setEditorPaneText(final String string) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            setString(string);
            EditorPane.setText(getString());
            EditorPane.repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried running the debugger but the processing skips from the first line of the method to the last curly bracket without processing the code within.  My Gui class has the following as a main method. The commented part was a previous version of the event queue that I changed while I was reading through the numerous posts on the issue.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Gui().setVisible(true);
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });
}
```

The following is the previous code of the main method that I replaced after reading some of the posts on this issue.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new Gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Any helpful information will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your debugger jumps to the end of the method because the code in the Runnable is executed in a different thread. Try setting a breakpoint in your run() method there.

Comment: Further you seem to create a second instance of your GUI. Don't do that.

Comment: I am creating Gui gui = new Gui() in another class not the main class. I do that so I can access its methods. Or is it not the right way?

Comment: where you create it, is not relevant. Just make sure that you don't create it twice. Your code snippets aboce looks like that. You have `new Gui()` twice there.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand as I'm still at an early Java stage. Can you please explain a little further how I can access a class' public methods? I don't know (yet) any another way to access a class' public methods. If this class is in another class file in the same project, isn't that the right way to use that class' public methods? Isn't that the same as creating for example List myList = new ArrayList (annotations)?

Comment: Yes, using that methods is 100% correct, but you create a second instance of the GUI. Just pass the variable to your worker thread. I will post an answer with some example code to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main error is that you create two instances of your Gui class. You have the following snippet twice: `new Gui()`. Take a look at my example code below to see an example how to pass the Gui to your worker thread.

```
// This is handwritte-untested-uncompiled code to show you what I mean
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           Gui g = new Gui();
           g.show(); // show() is equal to setVisible(true)
           g.doBackendAction(); // Normally this would be invoked by a button or sthg. I was to lazy
        }
     });
  }
}


public class Gui extends JFrame {
  private JTextArea area;
  public Gui() {
    // Just some code to create the UI. Not sure if this actually does sthg right :P
    area = new JTextArea();
    setContentPane(area);
    pack();
  }


  public void setTextAreaContent(final String string) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            area.setText(string);
            this.repaint(); // Not 100% sure if we need this

        }
    });
  }

  public void doBackgroundWork() {
    BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    new Thread(w).start(); // Start a worker thread
  }
}

public class BackgroundWorker implements Runnable {
   private Gui gui;
   public BackgroundWorker(Gui gui) {
     this.gui = gui; // we take the initial instance of Gui here as a parameter and store it for later
   }

   public void run() {
     try { Thread.sleep(10 * 1000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {; }
     this.gui.setTextAreaContent("Hello World!"); // calls back to the Gui to set the content 

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. To sum up and see if I understood: All the above code goes in the main class that "draws" the interface and if I need to update the text area from another class I just call setTextAreaContent from within the other class. I think a major problem I will have is to adapt this code to my present code because I drew the interface using swing components drag and drop buttons etc and my Main class is the one that extends JFrame and main(String args[]) is just running a SwingUtilities.invokelater... with just a new instance of the userinterface class set to visible(true)

Comment: No, I dont think you got it right and neither do you need to adapt your code. You may want to look into a tutorial which disucss objects. I think there lays the problem.